Spring security return 403 for all invalid request
I am using spring boot 3.4.0.
When I config security like this:
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    public static final String[] WHITE_LIST = {
            "/api/auth/**",
            "/api/public/**",
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/hello"
    };


    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, JwtFilter jwtFilter) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    for (String url : WHITE_LIST) {
                        auth.requestMatchers(url).permitAll();
                    }
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .sessionManagement(session ->
                        session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> {
                    //todo: I want to do it here
                })

                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        log.info("Created Password Encoder");
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}

But all the http requests, ex http://localhost:8080/test return 403 instead of 404 or 401, I want to do it in exceptionHandling for general status code.
Api not found should return 404
The API not in white list, will return 401 if it not be authenticated.

what is the reason for not enabling debug logs and reading the reason for your 403. Also building a justom jwtFilter is bad practice and not recommended, its very clear that you have only read a blog and not even read the spring security documentation before asking here. Delete you JWTFilter and read the docs how to build proper security.

When you get an error, Spring is trying to redirect you to /error
Since you're not authenticated and you protect everything that's not in your WHITE_LIST, you get a 403 since the un-authenticated client can't access /error
Add /error to your WHITE_LIST
Alternatively, you can add some controller advice like this, which will not redirect for 404 (but you'll have the same problem with other errors):
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomErrorController {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleNoHandlerFound(NoHandlerFoundException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Not Found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}


I added /error to while_list, the response seems to be /error, but the status code is not 404, still 403, I want it to be automatic like before using spring security, 405, 406 and more Status code always changes to 403

403 is the correct response. You explicitly allow certain stuff, and everything else is protected. Think about the filters that the request goes through, you have to but authenticated before you can attempt to access the not-found resource, so you get a 403 because you fail the first test before you even try to access the resource.

It's also a security issue, if you think about it, because if you return 403 for a valid resource and 404 for invalid when a user is not authenticated, you are disclosing information to an unauthenticated user (valid resource paths) and you probably should not be doing that.
